# Graphics2D awt port of copyArea method to playn

Tags: playn

I'm porting an old awt java game to playn framework,
I've some graphics.copyArea calls..
there is some way to map this call into some play.core.Canvas calls ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the same canvas as the source and destination of a `Canvas.drawImage` call:

```
CanvasImage image = graphics().createImage(100, 100);
// draw stuff in your canvas image

// define the source of the copyArea: 15x15+5+5
float sx = 5, sy = 5, swidth = 15, sheight = 15;
// note that we use swidth/sheight for dwidth/dheight because we don't want to scale,
// we just want to copy data from one place in the image to another
image.canvas().drawImage(image, 25, 25, swidth, sheight, sx, sy, swidth, sheight);
```

However, if you're really rendering everything to a Canvas on every frame, you're probably going to discover that that's very slow. You'll be better off restructuring things to use ImageLayer and other constructs that can be hardware accelerated.